# chmod 700 -R ~ - is it safe?

Tags: chmod, home-directory, read-write

I'm thinking of doing 'chmod 700 -R ~'. Can it be dangerous? What can happen what I don't expect? Also, is there any way to keep all files on $HOME to be -rwx------?

Comment: Why not just `chmod go-rx ~`? No need to recurse. (FWIW, some systems might not like it, e.g. when users publish web sites using `~/Sites` or `~/www` or something like that -- then the http server needs access to `~` -- but you'd know it if you did that).

Comment: Of course, if somebody made a copy of one of Anon’s world-readable files yesterday, there’s no way of recovering it.  But what if somebody made a hard link to one of his files?  `chmod`ing the home directory won’t affect that; he needs recursion to make the linked file private.

Comment: You don't have to do a recursive `chmod`. `chmod 700 ~` will keep all prying eyes out of your home directory.

Comment: @mtak: Ummm, Did you _read_ the existing comments?

Comment: How about doing `chmod 700 /home/*` instead of doing recursive. Since if access into parent directory's permission is denied, other users' will not able to access their sub-directories. If recursion is required after a new folder created under home `~` we have to change its permission. It might be difficult to keep track of all the new folders and update their permission. @Scott

Answer (score 7):

The main problem I can think of is that that command will set the e**x**ecute bit on all files, even those that aren’t executable.  So, if you have a file called `foo`, and someday you want to do `cat foo` or `print foo` and you accidentally type just `foo`, the shell will try to execute `foo`; i.e., interpret it as a shell script.  This will probably just explode in your face harmlessly, but if `foo` contains anything that looks like a shell command, you could get harmful results.

A lesser issue is that if you have a file that you want to preserve, and last year you did a `chmod 444` to protect it from yourself, the `chmod 700` will restore *your* **w**rite bit, and make it easier for you to clobber the file accidentally.

The solution to both issues is to do `chmod go= -R ~` or `chmod go-rwx -R ~`, which will turn off all bits for group and others, but leave your access alone.

Comment: Could I run `chmod 700 /home/*` instead of doing recursive. Since access into parent directory's permission is denied, other users' will not able to access their sub-directories. @Scott

Answer (score 0):

Kind of old now but you can `chmod 700` for folders and `chmod 600` files and it would solve the issue of adding the execute bit on all regular files (you need execute on folders to `ls`).

```
find ~ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 700
find ~ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 600
```

Comment: This GNU coreutils command has the same effect: `chmod -R ~ go-rwx,u+rwX`. It first removes group and world permissions, then adds read and write to the user and execute to directories. Warning: some files are expected to have an execute bit (like those in `~/bin/` or `node_modules/bin/`).